# How to setup tests with the appropriate code using rebar3?

Tags: automated-tests, erlang, eunit, rebar3

I have created a simple application via `rebar3` templates such as:

`apps/myapp/app/myapp_app.erl`

```
-module(myapp_app).

-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2, stop/1]).

start(_StartType, _Params) ->
    ok.

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

I have written a test for that:

`apps/myapp/test/myapp_test.erl`

```
-module(myapp_test).

-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

simple_test() ->
    myapp_app:start(ok, 42).
```

Sadly, when I launch the test, it seems that the link is not done between the two files:

```
$ rebar3 eunit
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling shoreline
===> Performing EUnit tests...
F
Failures:

  1) myapp_test:simple_test/0
     Failure/Error: {error,undef,
                        [{myapp_app,start,"*",[]},
                         {myapp_test,simple_test,0,
                             [{file,
                                  "/.../apps/myapp/test/myapp_test.erl"},
                              {line,8}]},
                         {myapp_test,simple_test,0,[]}]}
     Output:

Finished in 0.074 seconds
1 tests, 1 failures
===> Error running tests
```

Is there something to add in `rebar.config`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have .erl files in a custom directory other than 'src', then you need to add it to the code path.

You can do it using rebar3 by modifying `erl_opts` section in `'rebar.config'` as below.

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info, {src_dirs, ["src", "app"]}]}.
```

Hope this can work for you.

Answer (score 1):

`rebar3` does not find your `.erl` files if you have been under `/app` I moved them to `/src`.

```
➜  myapp rebar3 eunit
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Compiling myapp
===> Performing EUnit tests...
.
Finished in 0.081 seconds
1 tests, 0 failures
➜  myapp ls
LICENSE      README.md    _build       rebar.config src          test
➜  myapp mv src app
➜  myapp rebar3 eunit
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Performing EUnit tests...
F
Failures:

  1) myapp_test:simple_test/0: module 'myapp_test'
     Failure/Error: {error,undef,
                           [{myapp_app,start,[ok,42],[]},
                            {myapp_test,simple_test,0,[]}]}
     Output:

Finished in 0.036 seconds
1 tests, 1 failures
===> Error running tests
```

`undef` means could [not be found](http://www1.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html) when evaluating the call at runtime. [2](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-exceptions) To help see what `rebar3` is doing I can highly recommend [debug](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/configuration), `DEBUG=1`.